# How do I resolve this exception: com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException: AADSTS90002: Tenant 'tenant.id' not found?

Tags: java, azure, junit, mockito

- programming language:Java
- Context: I writing a junit test for a method that uses BlobClient uploadWithResponse method, but the method keeps throwing this exception. And I don't know how to resolve it.
- if anyone has resolved this problem, please help.

**com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException:**
AADSTS90002: Tenant 'tenant.id' not found. Check to make sure you have the correct tenant ID and are signing into the correct cloud. Check with your subscription administrator, this may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you please share the code that you are using? Looks like the problem with `DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you are passing in the string 'tenant.id' and not the actual Tenant ID, which is typically a GUID.